# Re-enter Schengen with a residence card

Tags: visas, schengen

I checked related questions, but they are more about visas, which is slightly different from my case.

I am a Chinese citizen holding a residence card in Norway. I have only a single entrance Schengen visa which has expired earlier this year. I plan to attend a conference in Ireland and a course at Svalbard. As Ireland and Svalbard are not Schengen area, I will leave Schengen area and re-enter when I come back. I am wondering if it is enough for me with my residence card, or if I need to apply for a new visa to enter Schengen area, (in my case just Norway)

Comment: Until I know, your residence works like a Visa. Also, I believe you will need a passport

Answer (score 3):

[Your residence permit is sufficient](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-nationals/index_en.htm):

> If your visa is from a Schengen area country, it automatically allows you to travel to the other Schengen countries as well. **If you have a valid residence permit from one of those Schengen countries, it is equivalent to a visa**.

This is [confirmed by the Norwegian Directorate of Immigration](https://www.udi.no/en/word-definitions/persons-who-do-not-need-a-visa-to-visit-norway-/#link-10562):

> #### Persons who do not need a visa to visit Norway (visa-free)
>
> ...
>
> - Persons with a valid resident permit or permanent residence permit in Norway. You must bring your residence card and passport.